# How to link android executable with .o file?

Tags: android-ndk

I want to link my executable with .o file, can I do this?

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := testo
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.c

include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

I created data.o file using ld -r -b binary data -o data.o

And I have this code:

```
extern int binary_data_size;
int main(){
printf("Data size: %d\n",binary_data_size);
return 0;
}
```

And i have error while compiling:

error: undefined reference to 'binary_data_size'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
LD_LIBS += data.o
```

Note that `Android.mk` is in the end just a makefile, so you can also have the line

```
data.o: binary data
    $(NDK_LD) -r -b binary data -o data.o
```

**ndk-build** evaluates `Android.mk` while the current directory is typically one level up. You also need the `ld` executable from the current NDK toolchain.